# Android consuming Web API using Retrofit 2 with a login activity

Tags: android, authentication, token, retrofit2

Greetings my fellow stacked developers,

I have multiple ASP.NET endpoints that I am trying to consume using Retrofit 2 Request Methods. I'm trying to create a login activity where upon entering and submit the credentials, fires off a POST to the endpoint which then provides the token information.  This authentication is required to then use GET calls for the data I'm trying to access on the backend.

I currently have the login activity, as well as the rest adapter and the interfaces for the Request Methods - I'm missing how I should pass the credentials to the Adapter within the login activity.

In summary I'd like to input the login credentials, create a POST to the endpoint, and receive the token, which takes me to the next page where I fire off the GET request for the actual data. Please recognize I'm a .NET developer by trade so if I'm missing large parts of the puzzle please feel free to let me know.  Any help is appreciated.

> Here's the LoginActivity/MainActivity
>
> ```html
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.net.Uri;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
> import android.widget.Button;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.widget.ProgressBar;
> import android.widget.TextView;
>
> import com.example.smcnary.insightv2.api.ServiceGenerator;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     //Set Error Status
>
>     static boolean errored = false;
>     Button b;
>     TextView statusTV;
>     EditText userNameET , passWordET;
>     ProgressBar webservicePG;
>     String editTextUsername;
>     boolean loginStatus;
>     String editTextPassword;
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>         //Name Text control
>         userNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
>
>         passWordET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
>         //Display Text control
>         statusTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
>         //Button to trigger web service invocation
>         b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>         //Display progress bar until web service invocation completes
>         webservicePG = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
>         //Button Click Listener
>         b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 //Check if text controls are not empty
>                 if (userNameET.getText().length() != 0 && userNameET.getText().toString() != "") {
>                     if(passWordET.getText().length() != 0 && passWordET.getText().toString() != ""){
>                         editTextUsername = userNameET.getText().toString();
>                         editTextPassword = passWordET.getText().toString();
>                         statusTV.setText("");
>                         Intent intent = new Intent(
>                                 Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
>                                 Uri.parse(ServiceGenerator.API_BASE_URL + "/token" + "?client_id=" + userNameET));
>                             startActivity(intent);
>
>                     }
>                     //If Password text control is empty
>                     else{
>                         statusTV.setText("Please enter Password");
>                     }
>                     //If Username text control is empty
>                 } else {
>                     statusTV.setText("Please enter Username");
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> The Adapter/ServiceGenerator:

```html
import android.util.Base64;
import com.example.smcnary.insightv2.model.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://figgg-identity.azurewebsites.net/token";

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
    }

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            String credentials = username + ":" + password;
            final String basic =
                    "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", basic);
                    requestBuilder.header("Accept", "application/json");
                    requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
        }

        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

    public interface LoginService {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/token")
        User Basiclogin(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password, Callback<User> callback);


    }


}
```

EDIT: Here are my JSON objects:

> AuthToken:

```html
package com.example.smcnary.insightv2.model;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class AuthToken {

    private String accessToken;
    private String tokenType;
    private Integer expiresIn;
    private String name;
    private String title;
    private String picImageBase64String;
    private String Issued;
    private String Expires;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The accessToken
     */
    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param accessToken
     * The access_token
     */
    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The tokenType
     */
    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param tokenType
     * The token_type
     */
    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The expiresIn
     */
    public Integer getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param expiresIn
     * The expires_in
     */
    public void setExpiresIn(Integer expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The title
     */
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param title
     * The title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The picImageBase64String
     */
    public String getPicImageBase64String() {
        return picImageBase64String;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param picImageBase64String
     * The picImageBase64String
     */
    public void setPicImageBase64String(String picImageBase64String) {
        this.picImageBase64String = picImageBase64String;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Issued
     */
    public String getIssued() {
        return Issued;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Issued
     * The .issued
     */
    public void setIssued(String Issued) {
        this.Issued = Issued;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Expires
     */
    public String getExpires() {
        return Expires;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Expires
     * The .expires
     */
    public void setExpires(String Expires) {
        this.Expires = Expires;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

> User Object:

```html
public class User {
    @SerializedName("name")
    String name;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it a good practice, but I save user credential in `SharedPreferences` and keep it in your application (create a singleton in your Application class or using Dagger to build it) until the signout action taken place. And I use `Authenticator`: https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html. For example, we have those credentials store using `UserCredentials` class, then when the OkHttp client construct we can pass it via parameters.

```
 OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(UserCredentials userCredentials) {

         return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                 .authenticator(new CustomAuthenticator(userCredentials))
                 .build();
    }
```

With the `CustomAuthenticator` look something like this:

```
public class CustomAuthenticator implements Authenticator {

     @NonNull
     private final UserCredentials credentials;

     public CustomAuthenticator(@NonNull UserCredentials credentials) {
         this.credentials = credentials;
     }

     @Override
     public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
         String userToken = credentials.getToken();
         return response.request().newBuilder()
                 .header("Authorization", "Token " + userToken)
                 .build();
     } 
}
```

There methods for basic login as well. You can read from the link and try out.